# Excel showing hidden data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, microsoft-office-2003

-- Excel 2003 SP3 --

I have a spreadsheet which I know for certain has a large amount of hidden rows which are correctly hiding on my colleagues machines, and were correctly hiding on mine two days ago, but this morning I find the hidden flag is being ignored and all that hidden data is rendered.

Is there some checkbox, configuration option, or function key I have accidentally pressed or need to press?

Answer (score 0):

```
Format > Rows > Show
```

and

```
Format > Rows > Hide
```

No function key for these commands, unless someone has recorded a macro to execute them and assigned it to a key combination.

Comment: Dont' have Excel to try this right now, but can't you just select the rows and right click to the left of them?

Comment: No, this is how to hide/show them actively. My problem is that data which *is hiding* when other people view it is *not* hiding when I view it. The hiding part is not working.